# how to solve the error when install module 'mongoose' on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, mongodb, mongoose

I met a problem when install module 'mongoose' on Mac, the following is the install info:
[image]

it seems the error info has been written into builderror.log, the content of the builderror.log is:
[image]

when I type 'npm list', you can see mongoose is in the list:
[image]

however, under directory /usr/local/bin, you couldn't see module 'mongoose':
[image]

Now the problem is the system can't find the 'mongoose' module, just like:
[image]

the content of test.js is as following, just test whether can collect to the db:
[image]

This problem only happens when install module 'mongoose'. If install other modules, the system can find the module correctly. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Type `npm list` and check mongoose is in list or not. And also please provide your codes from **test.js**.

Comment: Do you have XCode command line tools installed?

Comment: I have added 'npm list' result and content of test.js, see as above.

Comment: I have installed Xcode command line tools, version is 2333

Comment: I just tested your codes and it is working. May I know you node version and npm version also? Please check with `node -v` and also `npm -v`.

Comment: my node version is 0.12.0, npm version is 2.5.1, mongodb version is 3.0.0

Comment: I haven't upgraded my mongo version to 3.0 yet. Currently working on `2.6.6`. I will upgrade and check with you again :)

Comment: Okay, I upgraded to `3.0` it is working perfectly. Will you do `npm remove mongoose` and try again with `sudo npm install mongoose`?

Comment: I have done that, but the problem still exists.

Comment: I have noticed there is no 'mongoose' binary file under /usr/local/bin, while other installed modules have.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run mongo in separate tab? Try to run **sudo mongod** and another tab **node test.js**

Comment: I have done that. But the result is still can't find module 'mongoose'

Comment: @levon You don't need `sudo` to run mongod.